# Hide/FadeOut a Table Row - jQuery

Tags: jquery

how do i hide a table row with jQuery [with simple effect] ?
I want the fadeout effect or want to hide the row with "slow" speed.
My code hides it very fast [it does exactly like `document.getElementById('id').style.display='none';`]

My code

```
$('#pic').animate({ opacity: 'hide' }, "slow");
$('#pic').fadeOut("slow");
```

`Edit`
I want to hide the **TD** of a TR

Comment: I think the problem is, that a table row is not block-element. @DanielB's solution does it for me. Alternatively you can insert a div-container in your cell and fade-out them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It should work fine with if you hide the td's instead

```
$('#pic td').fadeOut(1000);
```

Have a look at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nABRF/1/)

Comment: i've the same code in FF, but it just hides the row in a second :(

Comment: slow is 600 ms. you can define another time instead buy giving an int with ms instead of 'slow'

Comment: It seems to be a problem with hiding a whole row. I've edited my post.